# Check if azure databricks mount point exists from .NET

Tags: .net-core, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

I work on an app which does some kind of data engineering and we use Azure ADLS for data storage and Databricks for data manipulation. There are two approaches in order to retrieve the data, the first one uses the `Storage Account` and `Storage account secret key` and the other approach uses `mount point`. When I go with the first approach, I can successfully check, from .NET, whether the `Storage account` and it's corresponsive `Secret key` correspond to each other and return a message whether the credentials are right or not. However, I need to do the same thing with the `mount point` i.e. determine whether the `mount point` exists in `dbutils.fs.mounts()` or anywhere in the storage (I don't know how `mount point` exactly works and if it stores data in blob).

The flow for `Storage account` and `Secret key` is the following:

1. Try to connect using the `BlobServiceClient` API from Microsoft;
2. If it fails, return a message to the user that the credentials are invalid;
3. If it doesn't fail, proceed further.

I'm not that familiar with `/mnt/` and stuff because I mostly do .NET but is there a way to check from .NET whether a `mount point` exists or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount point is just a kind of reference to the underlying cloud storage. `dbutils.fs.mounts()` command needs to be executed on some cluster - it's doable, but it's not fast & cumbersome.

The simplest way to check that is to use [List command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/dbfs#--list) of DBFS REST API, passing the mount point name `/mnt/<something>` as `path` parameter. If it doesn't exist, you'll get error message `RESOURCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST`:

```json
{
  "error_code": "RESOURCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST",
  "message": "No file or directory exists on path /mnt/test22/."
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add my personal-access-token that starts like `dbapi...` as an Authorization header?

Comment: Yes, you need to authenticate. You can authenticate either via personal access token, or via AAD token (personal or service principal). Look into REST API docs - there is a separate section about authentication